# Why are UL lists messed up by CSS height attribute?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm puzzled by this.  In a nested list, by setting the height of LI elements the list, the items overlap. What is the explanation for this, and what is the proper way apply height without overlap effect?   (I want height, not padding or margins.)
[image: the ugly result]

```
.aaa {background:#ccf;}
.bbb {background:#fcc;}
.bbb li {height:25px;}

<ul class="aaa">
  <li>one one one</li>
  <li>two, too
     <ul>
       <li>alpha</li>
       <li>beta</li>
       <li>gamma</li>
     </ul>
     </li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>here comes four</li>
</ul>
<ul class="bbb">
  <li>one one one</li>
  <li>two, too
     <ul>
       <li>alpha</li>
       <li>beta</li>
       <li>gamma</li>
     </ul>
     </li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>here comes four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the output you are trying to achieve? Why did you put the height there?

Comment: Since you're setting the height of the list items, this is behaving as expected. You're not allowing that second item with the nested list to expand to what you would assume is the natural height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li>two, too
     <ul>   <-- this list is part of your LI
       <li>alpha</li>
       <li>beta</li>
       <li>gamma</li>
     </ul>
     </li>
```

Since you have a list nested in a list, the inner list overflows because it is bigger than 25px.

Use `min-height` instead of `height`.

Answer (score 0):

The second tier li is inheriting the CSS from the top tier li

You need come CSS like

```
ul li ul li {/*style to hit the bottom tier*/}
```

This looks like you are making a menu - Tuts like this (http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-vertical-menu/) could advise you for better code but Padding and margin are recognised techniques to achieve what you apparently want